# Spring security error in native spring class during OpenId Client Implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid-connect

MY app Initializer

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[]{ApplicationConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
```

}

ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "base package name")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/secured/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/secured/resources/");
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry intRegistry) {
    UserInfoInterceptor interceptor = new UserInfoInterceptor();
    intRegistry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}


@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setPrefix("/secured/resources/html/");
    bean.setSuffix(".html");
    bean.setOrder(1);
    return bean;
}


@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resource;
}

@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceHolder() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer prop = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resource = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource(
            "application.properties") };
    prop.setLocations(resource);
    return prop;
}
```

}

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
  //@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

      @Bean
      @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception{
    return super.authenticationManager();
      }

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();       
    web.expressionHandler(handler).ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(getopenIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(),
            AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
            openIdAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**");
    http.logout();
   //        http.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticationProvider());
}


@Bean
public void setObjectPostProcessor(ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor) {
    super.setObjectPostProcessor(objectPostProcessor);
}
```

}

MethodSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true,prePostEnabled = true,     proxyTargetClass = true)
 public class MethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
SecurityConfiguration secConfig;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(secConfig.getAuthenticationProvider());
   }
   }
```

SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends
    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

I have been trying to implement open id connect Mitreid client and have configured the security config as given above.Configurations based on [MITREID Client](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/simple-web-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml)

When I deploy I get the below error

```
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:222)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$1.postProcess(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:175)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96834940.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96834940$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ad1d6c4.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96834940.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 26 more
```

Have included relevant part of the security configuration.Tried to override ObjectPostProcessor as suggested [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/49) but am getting same error. Note: Am not using spring boot or spring loaded.
I am not able to figure out the mistake I am making.Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
Spring version : 4.1.6.RELEASE 
Spring security verison : 4.0.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: I have trying to resolve this for the past couple of days but its like I have hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jwtstore configuration was causing an issue with the spring security configuration.Moved the relevant code to another class and it got working.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution please? I hitting the same wall past couple of hours.

Comment: I've resolved my issue. I've looked through all spring initialization warnings and noticed that my `@Bean(name = "sAMLBootstrap")
  public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap()
  {
    return new SAMLBootstrap();
  }` was no declared as `static` and spring was warning me about it or dependencies will not be available for autowiring. After adding static exception related to `ObjectPostProcessor` gone.

Comment: @JenyaG great advice!